# Difference between one SPARQL (working) query and another one (not working)

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to get the `scorers` (`marcatori`) from this page: `http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Modena_Football_Club_1962-1963` using this SPARQL endpoint: `http://uriburner.com/sparql/`

If I use this query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?team
  ?club
  (group_concat(distinct ?scorer;separator=";;;") as ?scorers) 
WHERE {
SERVICE <http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql/> {
   ?value rdfs:label "Campionato italiano di calcio Serie A"@it .
   ?year <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?value . 
   ?team <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/league> ?year .
   ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/club> ?club .
   OPTIONAL { ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/marcatori> ?scorer 
   }
}

} 
GROUP BY ?team ?club 
ORDER BY ?club
LIMIT 1
```

I get no results, where as if I use this one:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?team
  ?club
WHERE {
SERVICE <http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql/> {
   ?value rdfs:label "Campionato italiano di calcio Serie A"@it .
   ?year <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?value . 
   ?team <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/league> ?year .
   ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/club> ?club 
}

} 
GROUP BY ?team ?club 
ORDER BY ?club
LIMIT 1
```

I correctly get:

```
{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["team", "club"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [
    { "team": { "type": "uri", "value": 
 "http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Modena_Football_Club_1962-1963" }  , 
 "club": { "type": "uri", "value": 
 "http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Modena_Football_Club" }} ] } }
```

Does anyone know why the first query returns empty?

Comment: Might be the Virtuoso anytime feature that returns an empty result in the given time. I  also tried the first query on the Italian DBpedia itself without the `SERVICE`, but it looks like it's hosted on an older Virtuoso version because the `group_concat` leads to an error.

Comment: @AKSW, correct thats why I was using the other endpoint because the Italian one doesn't support `group_concat`. I am not familiar with the Virtuoso anytime feature? Is there any workaround? Or do I need to screen scrape to get that info?

Comment: Your time would be well spent [convincing Marco of `it.dbpedia.org`](http://it.dbpedia.org/contatti/) to upgrade their instance to a [current Virtuoso](http://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/). You might also consider setting up [your own Virtuoso instance](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) to use in place of the public URIBurner instance, which does indeed have [Anytime Query](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksAnytimeSPARQLQuery) settings that are hitting you on the first query, because it takes a while to execute the subquery against `it.dbpedia.org`.

Comment: ahah @TallTed I did already email him earlier on with a link to this question. Ok, I'll look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

`(group_concat(distinct ?scorer;separator=";;;") as ?scorers)`

with

`sql:group_concat(?scorer, ";;;") as ?scorers`

This should work fine on http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql, not sure why you need URI burner.