# SPARQL query executes but returns empty

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

Can't get this SPARQL query to return results:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT 
  ?team
  ?club
  (sql:group_concat(?coach, ";;;") as ?coaches) 
  (sql:group_concat(?president, ";;;") as ?presidents) 
  (sql:group_concat(?scorer, ";;;") as ?scorers)
  ?date 
  ?position 
  WHERE {
  SERVICE <http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql/> {
     ?value rdfs:label "Campionato italiano di calcio Serie A"@it .
     ?year <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?value . 
     ?team <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/league> ?year .
     ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/presidente> ?president .
     ?team <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/coach> ?coach .
     ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/campionatoPosizione> ?position .
     ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/stagione> ?date .
     ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/club> ?club .
     OPTIONAL { ?team <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/marcatori> ?scorer }
     FILTER( 1946 < ?date )
  }} group by ?team ?date ?position ?club LIMIT 1
```

The service used to run it is [URIBURNER](http://uriburner.com/sparql/)

Comment: it's the same problem as in your previous question...old version of DBpedia and the SERVICE clause has to gather all data from the endpoint before it can do the aggregate function stuff. And as suggested last time, you should contact the maintainer and suggest to update to latest Virtuoso. If you don't want to do this, for whatever reason, feel free to download DBpedia into your own local Virtuoso instance

Comment: @AKSW ok but in the other case it wasn't an old version of DBPedia, I got it running, that example, with Marco's suggestion, the issue was that `group_contact` doesn't work with `distinct`. Maybe this one is, not sure.

Comment: ok, but `group_concat` works with `distinct` - it's just more expensive. It's part of the SPARQL standard. And the main problem remains, the Virtuoso version is old, you can't just run your query on the Italian DBpedia endpoint because it doesn't support `group_concat` at all. That's weird, to be honest I don't know the reason for not updating.

Comment: moreover, when you run your query which already makes use of the `sql:group_concat` workaround on their endpoint, you'll get an error `Virtuoso 22023 Error SR319: Max length of a temp row (9206)  exceeded` - another reason for setting up a newer version and check the config settings in addition.

Comment: So you are saying that this query won't be able to run asking for all these details in the current state @AKSW

Comment: I can only say that 1) the whole query here doesn't work on the Italian DBpedia endpoint 2) a query with just the triple patterns isn't empty when running on the Italian DBpedia endpoint, so 3) I'm sure the SERVICE clause tries to retrieve all data and does the grouping part but stops execution because of the Virtuoso anytime feature. Clearly, The maintainer and devs of Virtuoso, like user TallTed might give you a better answer. And you could still host your own instance of the Italian DBpedia. Data + triple stores are free luckily

Comment: Thanks @AKSW, could you please clarify: 2) a query with just the triple patterns isn't empty when running on the Italian DBpedia endpoint

Comment: As @AKSW has said, the root of the problem here is the VERY old Virtuoso (`06.01.3127` built Sep 15 2014) that is providing the Italian DBpedia endpoint. Your best immediate option is to convince Marco et al to upgrade that Virtuoso. That said, note that it.dbpedia.org is configured to only ever return 1000 results -- so you will not get complete results for queries with larger solution sets, including this one, so you may need to rethink your process.

Comment: Thanks @TallTed, when you say 1000 results, is this for the whole query after the data has been aggregated, or 1000 results overall, meaning 1000 data points from DBPedia?

Comment: As the <http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql/> page says, "(The query results are limited to 1000 records)"  This means the result set is truncated at 1000 records, similar to what you would get from `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0`. (You can get the next 1000 with `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000`. Which would be a somewhat rethought process...)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments --

The root of the problem here is the VERY old Virtuoso (06.01.3127 built Sep 15 2014) that is providing the Italian DBpedia endpoint. Your best immediate option is to convince Marco et al to upgrade that Virtuoso.

That said, note that the  page says, *"(The query results are limited to 1000 records)".* This means the result set is truncated at 1000 records, similar to what you would get from `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0`. (You can get the next 1000 with `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000`. Which would be a somewhat rethought process...)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using URI Burner?

Your query only pulls data from the Italian DBpedia endpoint, so:

1. do not use the `SERVICE` clause;
2. just run it on http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql !

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53529798/10719765

In addition, query result sets are **explicitly** limited to **1,000** rows: this is also meant to avoid query execution timeouts.

If your query times out, you need to implement a paging mechanism via `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. For instance:

```
SELECT ?musician
WHERE { ?musician a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MusicalArtist> . }
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 1000
```

The next page would be `OFFSET 1000 LIMIT 2000` and so on.

Comment: I think you didn't try running the query directly on the Italian DBpedia endpoint with your suggested workaround from the other question, which you'll see produces "temp row max length" errors, because that endpoint is running on a very old version of Virtuoso, all of which was discussed in the comments on the question.